# LSTM Model Implementation

Tags: python, deep-learning, sequence, lstm

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=1, output_size=1, hidden_size=100, num_layers=16):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers)

        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)

        self.num_layers = num_layers

        self.hidden_cell = (torch.zeros(self.num_layers,12 ,self.hidden_size).to(device),
                            torch.zeros(self.num_layers,12 ,self.hidden_size).to(device))

    def forward(self, input_seq):
        #lstm_out, self.hidden_cell = self.lstm(input_seq.view(len(input_seq) ,1, -1), self.hidden_cell)
        lstm_out, self.hidden_cell = self.lstm(input_seq, self.hidden_cell)        
        predictions = self.linear(lstm_out[:,-1,:])

        return predictions
```

This is my LSTM model, Input is a 4 dimension vector. Batch size is 16 and time stamp is 12. I want to find 13th vector with using 12 sequence vector.  My LSTM block have [16,12,48] output. I did not understand why i have choose the last one:
`out[:,-1,:]`

Comment: The reason you choose the last one `lstm_out[:, -1, :]` is because the linear layer on top of LSTMs will get the output of the last LSTM layer as input.

Comment: My network converge mean of our dataset, is there any reason to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how it looks, your problem is like a text (i.e., sequence) classification problem, with `output_size` being the number of classes that you want to assign text to. By choosing `lstm_out[:,-1,:]`, you actually intend to predict the label associated with the input text only using the **last hidden state** of your LSTM network, which totally makes sense. This is what people commonly do for text classification problems. Your linear layer, thereafter, will output logits for each class, and then you can use `nn.Softmax()` to get the probabilities of those.

The last hidden state of the LSTM network is the propagation of all previous hidden states of the LSTM, meaning that it has the aggregated information of previous input states that it has encoded (let's consider that you're using uni-directional LSTM as in your example). So for classifying an input text, you will have to do the classification based on the overall information of all tokens within the input text (which is encoded in the last hidden state of your LSTM). That is why you feed *only* the last hidden state to the linear layer that is upon your LSTM network.

*Note:* If you intended to do sequence-tagging (such as Named-entity recognition), then you would use all the hidden state outputs from your LSTM network. In such tasks, you would actually need information about a specific token within the input.